Align the widget with image without using width on Flutter web

Hi, How can i align the widget below the image without using a fixed width? the reason I don't want to use fixed width(or can use fixed width but as long as it able to adjust with resizing) is because when resizing i want to shrink the side spacing to close up while the widget can align left with the image.
here is the expected layout

and here is the expected behavior when the browser width is resized to smaller width (the spacing on the side is shrinked while maintaining the layout

Here is my current code
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    width: Sizes.dynamicWidth(context),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        colors: [
          FabricColors.ashGrey.withOpacity(.4),
          FabricColors.ashGrey.withOpacity(.2),
          FabricColors.ashGrey.withOpacity(0),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: Sizes.dynamicHeight(context) * .8,
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                cacheKey: Uri.parse(widget.media.data.imageUrl!).replace(queryParameters: new Map<String, dynamic>()).toString(),
                imageUrl: widget.media.data.imageUrl!,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                placeholder: (_, url) => _buildPlaceholder(),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) {
                  BlocProvider.of<FabricImageBloc>(context).add(FabricImageErrorEvent(error));
                  return _buildError(boxDecoration, i, defaultAsset);
                },
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Container(
                padding: Spaces.smallAll,
                margin: Spaces.smallAll,
                width: Sizes.dynamicWidth(context) - 900,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: FabricColors.boscoGrey, borderRadius: Radiuses.mediumCircle),
                child: IntrinsicHeight(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Avatar(
                                url: widget.avatarUrl,
                                size: Sizes.small,
                              ),
                              Spaces.miniWidth,
                              FabricText(
                                widget.media.role,
                                style: FabricTheme.of(context).pastelPurpleTextTheme.caption3,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          SvgIcon(Assets.lib.assets.svg.moreHorizontal),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Spaces.smallHeight,
                      FabricText(
                        widget.media.title,
                        style: FabricTheme.of(context).blancoTextTheme.bodySmall,
                      ),
                      Spaces.smallHeight,
                      Expanded(
                        child: FabricText(
                          widget.media.description,
                          style: FabricTheme.of(context).blancoTextTheme.caption3,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Spaces.smallHeight,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


Try below code hope its help to you. Just replace my Widget with your
Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [
            Colors.grey.withOpacity(.4),
            Colors.grey.withOpacity(.2),
            Colors.grey.withOpacity(0),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Image.network(
                'https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1317323736/photo/a-view-up-into-the-trees-direction-sky.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=i4HYO7xhao7CkGy7Zc_8XSNX_iqG0vAwNsrH1ERmw2Q=',
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  width: 400,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                  child: IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.person),
                                SizedBox(width: 20),
                                Text('Title')
                              ],
                            ),
                            Icon(Icons.more_vert)
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        Text('title'),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),


it's aligned left and not as expected layout, the expected layout was to keep the side spacing but the widget on the bottom is aligned left with the image above it

@RakaPrasetyo have you try above code in web?

I did tried it yes, it's still not working as intended. the image and the widget aligned left where the image supposed to be in the center, but the widget is kinda in the center but aligned left with spacing on the left where the spacing should be shrinked when user resize the browser
